# Button name option is missing for headless mode when send patch request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

I have a form which sends PATCH request with multiple submitting buttons

```
button_tag "Save", type: "submit", class: "btn btn-secondary", name:  "commit", value: "save"
button_tag "Submit", type: "submit", class: "btn btn-secondary", name:  "button", value: "submit"
```

there is controller action which check clicked button value.

```
def update
  params[:commit].to_s.downcase == "save"
  ....
end
```

It returns true for development mode and using selenium driver, it breaks for a headless mode when I use poltergeist javascript_driver. In this case, the value is absent.

I have tested it using click_on "Save" command

What can be wrong with the headless browser that I can't get value eventually to compare which button was clicked?

Thanks so much in advance for advising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the submission is AJAX driven using an actual PATCH request (as opposed to a POST request that passes a hidden `_method` parameter set to 'PATCH').

Due to the version of QtWebkit PhantomJS (used by Poltergeist as its "browser") is built with it has an issue where the bodies of actual patch requests are always empty. Being based on QtWebkit (which was EOL'd) leaves PhantomJS approximately equivalent to a 6-7 year old browser and becoming less and less capable for testing modern JS driven applications. You're probably going to be better off just using Selenium with headless chrome for headless testing instead.

Comment: Thanks, It's really helpful. headless chrome works perfect for this case

Comment: @TaniaFilonenko You're welcome, if your question is solved don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this to be a browser support issue. Looking at the docs for [`button_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag), it states:

> You can use the button tag as a regular submit tag but it isn't supported in legacy browsers

You're probably better off using a checkbox to indicate the difference in state here.

Additionally, you're mixing concerns within your `update` method -- it should really only have one responsibility of updating the record in question, not submitting it too. You're probably better off using an additional controller and `button_to` for your "submit" functionality. [More reading](http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/) on the topic.